# N1QL Query to connect databricks spark 1.6 to couchbase server 4.5

Tags: scala, couchbase, sql++, databricks

I am trying to setup a connection from Databricks to couchbase server 4.5 and then run a N1QL query.

The scala code below will return 1 record but fails when introducing the N1QL. Any help is appreciated.

```
    import com.couchbase.client.java.CouchbaseCluster;
    import scala.collection.JavaConversions._;

    import com.couchbase.client.java.query.Select.select;
    import com.couchbase.client.java.query.dsl.Expression;
    import com.couchbase.client.java.query.Query



    // Connect to a cluster on localhost
    val cluster = CouchbaseCluster.create("http://**************")

    // Open the default bucket
    val bucket = cluster.openBucket("travel-sample", "password");

    // Read it back out
    //val streamsense = bucket.get("airline_1004546") - Works and returns one record


  // Create a DataFrame with schema inference
    val ev = sql.read.couchbase(schemaFilter = EqualTo("type", "airline"))

    //Show the inferred schema
     ev.printSchema()

    //query using the data frame
    ev
      .select("id", "type")
      .show(10)


    //issue sql query for the same data (N1ql)
    val query = "SELECT type, meta().id  FROM `travel-sample` LIMIT 10"
    sc
      .couchbaseQuery(N1qlQuery.simple(query))
      .collect()
      .foreach(println)
```

Comment: I can't find it but I believe you have to use a special backend that they developed and not the standard CouchDB or MemCachedDB.

Comment: hi, I am using databricks to run all spark jobs and attempting to bring the data into memory for further analysis through the databricks eco system.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Databricks (and any interactive Spark cloud environment usually) you do not define the cluster nodes, buckets or sc variable, instead you need to set the configuration settings for Spark to use when setting up the Databricks cluster.  Use the advanced settings option as shown below.

I've only used this approach with spark2.0 so your mileage may vary.

[image]
You can remove your cluster and bucket variable initialisation as well.

Answer (score 1):

You have a syntax error in the N1QL query. You have:

```
val query = "SELECT type, id  FROM `travel-sample` WHERE LIMIT 10"
```

You need to either remove the WHERE, or add a condition.

You also need to change id to META().id.

Comment: Thanks Geraldss you are correct. Although I have just pushed the fix through and still does not work. I will update the main code with your suggestions.